# Application.LoadLevel Unity not working properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameManagement script that loads levels based on player lives/key input/score. Here it is:

```
void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && (CurrentLevel == "start")){
            Application.LoadLevel ("level1");
        }

        if (CharacterMovement.Score == 10) {
            CharacterMovement.Score = 11;
            Application.LoadLevel ("level2");

        }

        if (CharacterMovement.Lives <= 0) {
            CurrentLevel = "lose";
            Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Return) && (CurrentLevel == "lose")) {
            Application.LoadLevel ("start");
        }


    }
```

The problem is on the lose screen. When I press the return key, absolutely nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: obviously two thing either update is not working or urrentLevel == "lose" is not true!

Answer (score 0):

Without the full code all I can do is guess, because your check for the return key makes sense I can only assume that the current level is not evaluating to "lose".

Consider making "CurrentLevel" a public variable and than watch what it equals in the unity inspector at the moment you want this to happen.

If this is evaluating correctly, please consider sharing more code so we can come up with a better solution! (Sorry I did not add this as a comment, not enough rep)

Comment: Alright so I tried that, but once I get to the lose scene, I'm not even able to click on my GameManager object to see what the value of the string is. The inspector keeps flickering between what's in the lose scene and several instances "deleted gameobject," leaving me unable to select my GameManager.